# EF Codefirst validate unique property?

Tags: entity-framework, code-first

Curious about how to efficiently validate that a given property of a CodeFirst model is unique.  Classic example being a member's username or display name.

Traditionally I might do this by setting a Unique constraint in the database, or alternatively by doing a lookup during an attempted insert operation.  I know how to manually add these things in the DB itself after generation, just wanting to see if there's a way to do it as part of the schema mapping provided by the framework.

***UPDATE***
I found that I can override the ValidateEntity method on the DbContext, which conceptually would allow me to do a lookup and then invalidate the object to prevent the save.  I'd still be curious to know if there's a way to apply a Unique constraint or similar in the database

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Code First (and EF in general) *still* does not natively support unique constraints. In [**this post**](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/01/23/associations-in-ef-code-first-ctp5-part-3-one-to-one-foreign-key-associations.aspx) I showed one way to create them at the same time that your database is get created by Code First (via SQLCommand method in a custom Initializer class) but it's not really different from manually creating it yourself. The other way is `ValidateEntity` which you've suggested, but I would still create the unique constraints on the database anyways.

Answer (score 0):

**I have posted about this at [code project](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1143215/Validate-a-Unique-Constraint-at-dbContext-Validate)**

In general, it depends on the attributes that you put on the classes to generate your unique indexes